# Correct Form for naming method parameters that clash with property names

Tags: objective-c, parameters, properties

If I have a class with a property of `notificationCenter`, and implement a method with this signature:

```
-(void)doSomethingWithNotificationCenter:(NSNotificationCenter *)notificationCenter
```

Xcode rightly gives me an error:

> 'local declaration of notificationCenter hides instance variable'

So in Objective C is there a convention for naming this parameter to avoid this collision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter should be called `aNotificationCenter` or possibly `aCenter`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a personal preference, I have seen aNotificationCenter as mentioned above, inNotificationCenter, theNotificationCenter among others. I think as long as you are consistent in your own code any basic, readable choice is OK.

PS - my personal preference is inNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use the format receivedNotificationCenter or notificationCenterParam.